# using a model's function in _.map from within a collection

Tags: javascript, function, backbone.js, underscore.js

I use backbonejs and underscorejs. I have a `Person` model with a `getFullName()` function and a `Persons` collection with a `getSummary()` which should return all full names of the persons contained. My current implementation is:

```
var Person = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        name: '',
        surname: ''
    },
    getFullName: function() {
        return this.get('name') + ' ' + this.get('surname');
    }
});

var Persons = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Person,
    getSummary: function() {
        return _.map(this.models, function(person) {
            return person.getFullName();
        }).join(', ');
    }
});

console.log(
    new Persons([
        {name: 'john', surname: 'smith'},
        {name: 'mary', surname: 'poppins'}
    ]).getSummary()
);
```

This works well and I get the following displayed in the console:

```
john smith, mary poppins
```

My problem is that I don't want to be so verbose in the `getSummary()` function. I'd like to simply be able to pass the model's function instead of having to create a function to call it. Maybe something like this:

```
getSummary: function() {
    return _.map(this.models, 'model.getFullName').join(', ');
}
```

Is this possible somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Backbone proxies a lot of Underscore functions on collections and models, most notably the very nice [`_.invoke`](http://underscorejs.org/#invoke) :

> **invoke** `_.invoke(list, methodName, *arguments)`
>   Calls the method named by methodName on each value in the list. Any extra arguments
>   passed to invoke will be forwarded on to the method invocation.

You can simplify your method like this:

```
getSummary: function() {
    return this.invoke('getFullName').join(', ');
}
```

And a Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/pxpon64q/